# Find all degree solutions in the interval $0^\circ \leq \theta < 360^\circ$.

Tags: trigonometry

Find all degree solutions in the interval $0^\circ \leq \theta < 360^\circ$. If rounding is necessary, round to the nearest tenth of a degree.

$$5\sin^2 \theta − 6\cos2θ= 0$$

My work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjPpb.jpg

Comment: Why not use a calculator to get the final answer?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Well, you seem to have reached $\cos^2{\theta}=11/17$, so just square root 11/17 and then take the inverse cosine (also called acos, $\cos^{-1}$, or arccos). Also remember to do the inverse cosine of -11/17, and include all the angles that could have either value for $\cos{\theta}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\cos(2\theta) = 1 - 2\sin^2(\theta)$
You might find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up from were you left off, we have

$$\cos^2\theta=\frac{11}{17}$$
Hence 
$$\cos\theta=\pm\sqrt{\frac{11}{17}}$$

Noting that $\left|\pm\sqrt{\frac{11}{17}}\right|<1$, we know that there are $2$ solutions for $\cos\theta=\sqrt{\frac{11}{17}}$ and $2$ solutions for $\cos\theta=-\sqrt{\frac{11}{17}}$ in the interval $[0^\circ,360^\circ)$. Recalling that $\cos\theta=\cos(360^\circ-\theta)$ and that the [$\cos^{-1}$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCosine.html) has range $[0,180^\circ]$, we have that our $4$ solutions are:
$$\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{11}{17}}\right),\hspace{5mm}\cos^{-1}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{11}{17}}\right),\hspace{5mm}360^\circ-\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{11}{17}}\right),\hspace{5mm}360^\circ-\cos^{-1}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{11}{17}}\right)$$